# How to set up single PayPal button to sell multiple quantities of one product with variable shipping.

Tags: paypal

I have a single item I need to sell on my website through PayPal.

I am having a tough time setting this form up with PayPal

Buyers may purchase multiple quantities.

If three or less are ordered the shipping price is the USPS priority price of $5.30. 4-6 is $10.60, 7-9 $15.90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out... Unfortunately, the PayPal documentation does not mention that a user must be a Business level user to enter separated shipping details.